# How to fit an interference pattern with Interpolation and FindFit？

Tags: fitting, interpolation

I have two sets of experimental data.

[LightSourceSpectrum2.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AgfBjRUVmSdHdZfd9qiq3VPHAmk?e=a4CF50)

[InterferencePattern2.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AgfBjRUVmSdHdn82Y3iaXIifnGY?e=osmwYa)

The first one is the light source spectrum data, which can become a function of f[ν] using Interpolation. (Note f[ν] is the spectrum and ν is frequency.)

```
    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
    m0 = Import["LightSourceSpectrum2.txt", "Table"];
    ListPlot[m0, PlotLabel -> "Light Source Spectrum", Joined -> True,  Mesh -> None, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 10],  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black], Axes -> None,   PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True,  FrameLabel -> {Style["Frequency (THz)", 15],    Style["Intensity (a.u.)", 15]}, AspectRatio -> .67,   ImageSize -> {300, 200}]
    f = Interpolation[m0]
```

[image]

The second one is the interference data, which has the thoetical model of  model =  y0 + A*f[ν] (Cos[2π ν (t)] + 1), where t is time, ν is frequency. I need to fit the  interference data  using  f[ν] and  the model. The following is my code.  But the fitting result is not good.

```
    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
    m1 = Import["InterferencePattern2.txt", "Table"];
    model = y0 + A*f[ν] (Cos[2π ν (t)] + 1); 
    f1 = FindFit[m1, model, {{y0, 0}, {A, 1}, {t, 0.95}}, ν, Method -> NMinimize]

    fig1 = ListPlot[m1, PlotLabel -> "Interference Pattern ",  Joined -> True, Mesh -> None, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 10], FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black], Axes -> None, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black},  FrameLabel -> {Style["Frequency (THz)", 15], Style["Intensity (a.u.)", 15]}, AspectRatio -> .67, ImageSize -> {600, 400}];
    fig2 = Plot[Evaluate[model /. {f1}], {ν, 191.001, 196.39874},    PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,    Axes -> False,    FrameLabel -> {Style["Frequency (THz)", 15], Style["Intensity (a.u.)", 15]}];
    Show[fig1, fig2 ]
```

[image]

The purpose of fitting the interference data is to estimate the parameter of t with high accuracy. I fit it with a cosine function because the optical interference pattern is usually discribed by a cosine function in theroy. But there are some difference between the theory model and experimental data.

I also plot the ratio of the two curves (the spectrum and interference pattern), which is cosine-like.

[image]

My question is: how to perform a good fiting for the interference data?   Any help or suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure you can do a lot better. The model just doesn't describe the data more accurately: If you plot the ratio of the two curves (the spectrum and interference pattern), you can see that the result is far from a cosine (which it mostly should be if your model is correct)

Comment: You need to consult with a statistician.  One thing they would tell you is to look at the residuals vs v.  Patterns (if any) you would see would suggest what modifications in the model might be necessary.  You also should use `NonlinearModelFit` rather than `FindFit` as the former has lots of diagnostic tools.  For example the plot of the residuals mentioned could be found with `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[m1, model, {{y0, 0}, {A, 1}, {t, 0.95}}, \[Nu], Method -> NMinimize]; ListPlot[Transpose[{m1[[All, 1]], nlm["FitResiduals"]}], Joined -> True]`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data? Is there a reason you have to fit it with a cosine? It doesn’t match a cosine very well. If you want a better fit, you’ll probably need a more complicated model. But depending on what you want to do, a fit may not be necessary at all. Perhaps a Fourier transform or some other technique might be more appropriate.

Comment: @MassDefect, Thanks a lot for the suggestion. The purpose  of fitting the interference data is to estimate the parameter of t with high accuracy. I fit it with a cosine function because the optical interference  pattern is usually discribed by  a  cosine function in theroy. But there are some difference between the theory model and experimental data.

Comment: What good is an estimate with high accuracy if the data doesn't match the model (or the other way around)? "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is." Yogi Berra.  Although...the estimate of `t` is 0.91003 and the estimate of the standard error is only 0.0000203777.

Comment: There is a problem in my previous data, and the ratio is not like cosine. I have update it now.@JimB @ Lukas Lang

Comment: Try `f1 = FindFit[m1, model, {{y0, 0}, {A, 1}, {b, 1}, {t, 0.95}}, \[Nu], Method -> NMinimize]`

Comment: @Cesareo, Thanks a lot for the suggestion. The fitting result is better now. But I donot understand the reason. "b" is a parameter which is not exist in the model. Why the result is improved with b?

Comment: Use also `model = y0 + A*f[\[Nu]] (Cos[2 Pi \[Nu] (t)] + b)`

Comment: @JimB, Thank you very much for the good suggestion. I have tried NonlinearModelFit, which has better diagnostic tools.